# Show $\sum_{ r = 0}^{n} {(\binom n r)}^{2} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^{2}}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How do we show that this identity holds for any n? Any hints or solutions?

Show $\sum_{ r = 0}^{n} {(\binom n r)}^{2} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^{2}}$

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: A broad hint: write one of your two $n\choose r$ terms as $n\choose n-r$ using the symmetry of the binomial coefficients. From there you should be able to apply familiar identities...

Comment: Already tried this but still stuck, can you give more hints?

Comment: See [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Comment: For $~n=\dfrac12~$ we have $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}^2}{16^n~(2n-1)^2}=\frac4\pi$